# RIA Service exposed with SOAP Endpoint. Cant get entity's members

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services, datacontract, datamember

There is a WCF RIA service exposed via SOAP endpoint. I added this service as a service reference to an another project. When I invoke service's method, i get pleased entity but without nested entites. In other words, there are no `[DataMember]` attributes on nested members of the entity.

I tried to add `[DataMember]` attribute on entity's members, but it doesnt work.

Entity:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PlnCheckMeta))]
public partial class PlnCheck : IEntityChangeLogable
{

}

public partial class PlnCheckMeta
{
    [Composition]
    [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
    public IList<PlnCheck> PlnCheckList { get; set; } // can't get this member 
                                                      // in service reference 
                                                      // generated entity
}
```

Is there any idea how to expose nested members?

Comment: I've decided to deal with simple WCF Service instead of RIA Service.

Answer (score 0):

Add an [Include] attribute to PlnCheckList

Comment: The Include attribute only work within the regular wcf ria services endpoint.